# Inject a submit button and submit the form when clicking on a link

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a form with an id and name. What I would like to do is when I click on a link, inject an html submit button in the form and then submit the form. Can this be done using jQuery?

Comment: Yes it can. What have you tried?

Comment: Why inject anything?  Just do the submit when the link is clicked.

Comment: An example of what you are trying helps.  Try posting code somewhere like http://jsfiddle.net and adding the link to your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do something, but without seeing any of your code here is a generic example in jQuery showing how to `submit` a form with `id` `myForm` by clicking a link with `id` `myLink`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myLink').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#myForm').submit();
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="myLink">submit the form</a>
```

Comment: Except you MUST return false or call e.preventDefault()

Answer (score 0):

Look at using the `.add()` or `.append()` methods.

http://api.jquery.com/add/

http://api.jquery.com/append/

You could set up a listener to handle the event when the button is added.

```
$(document).on('#btnSubmit', 'click', function() {
    // do something
});
```

You could also add a method call to the `onclick` attribute, if you wanted.